# Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie" error in browser yet request is successful

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angularjs. When I set `Cookie` header with `xhr.setRequestHeader()` I get the following error on Chrome:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"
```

However, the `Cookie` is included into the request and successfully sent to server. I seem to have configured everything correctly to allow `Cookie` header on server and client:

for server I have these:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

for client I specify these:

```
withCredentials
```

Why is this error?

Comment: I guess the browser handles the cookie headers by itself.

Comment: hey, thanks, what do you mean by that? :)

Comment: I know that Chrome won't allow you to set content-length for example. It does that for you. So I guess it's maybe the same with the cookie header.

Comment: @Mouser, I guess that's exactly it! After I've removed `setRequestHeader()` from my code the `Cookie` header is still passed to the server. Thanks! Best luck!

Comment: @Maximus: how did you solve this? can you post your code

Comment: @ParthDoshi, Chrome seems to prevent usage of `setRequestHeader` with `Cookie` header, so I just removed this line from code. Despite the fact that I removed this method, Chrome still sends this header.

Comment: ok. In my project i want to set Cookie header as "Cookie", "test123" but then how do I send this cookie across. Chrome sends the default cookie value that includes csrftoken etc. So how do i ensure my value goes inside  the that without any error?

Comment: You need to set this cookie using JS, and then Chrome will send it automatically

Comment: I have the same issue in AngularJS 1.3.15. I have seted in header config, but for the same version is not working.

Comment: @wanttobeprofessional, what do you mean? maybe create another question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You get that error from Chrome because, per [the XHR specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-setrequestheader()-method), the `setRequestHeader` method should not set headers with a [forbidden header name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name).

Per the specification:

> > These are forbidden so the user agent remains in full control over them.

Instead, for Angular 1.x, [set the cookie](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) by using `$cookies`, and it will be included in subsequent `xhr` requests.

Answer (score 0):

#### *This "template" works for me*

---

<sub>open developer-tools and try run `$.ajax` placing the `setRequestHeader` in the `beforeSend` method.</sub>

---

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
  header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
?><!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script defer="defer" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

<sub>taken From **[Liberated HTML5](http://icompile.eladkarako.com/liberated-html5/)**, and [**W3C**'s *Cross-Origin Resource Sharing*](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#syntax).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

if you have the cookies sent over, i think that would be good enough. Having "        crossDomain: true,
        withCredentials: true
" solved the issue of "Refused to set unsafe header “Cookie”" i encountered as well. Even though the alert message still there, however, i have the cookie sent over and have correct response back.

Comment: yeah, everything works OK, it's just the message that annoys