# Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, xmlhttprequest

```
function sendToken():void{
    console.log("In sendToken();")
    var cookie_name="auth_token_seven";
    var xhr;
    var hash;
    if(!docCookies.getItem(cookie_name)){
        console.log("Token not found!");
        hash="8617f366566a011837f4fb4ba5bedea2b892f3ed8b894023d16ae344b2be5881";
        this.docCookies.setItem(cookie_name,hash,"/",4000, true);
        console.log("Token set");
        xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST","myurl", true);
        xhr.withCredentials=true;
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie",cookie_name=hash);
        xhr.send();
    }

    else{
        console.log("Token found");
        hash=docCookies.getItem(cookie_name);
        console.log("getting Token");
        xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "myurl", true);
        xhr.withCredentials=true;
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie_name=hash);
        xhr.send();
    }
```

Hi, I am using cookie.js to set a cookie when a user logins on my website.
What I am trying to do, is to set a auth token inside the cookie whenever a user logins on my website, this cookie with the auth token, is sent to the server, whenever the user tries to access some features on my site.

The problem, I am facing is, Chrome disallows the setting of cookie by showing an alert message **Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"**.

I looked at one of the links [Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie" error in browser yet request is successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255284/refused-to-set-unsafe-header-cookie-error-in-browser-yet-request-is-successful).
I tried my way around , but it's still not working.

Can anyone please suggest a solution.

Comment: Only the accepted answer on the duplicate question is correct. If you want to send a cookie, then you have to set it explicitly (either with `document.cookies` or a `Set-Cookie` header from the server). You can't do it with addRequestHeader.