# AngularJS Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am using an AngularJS application to make a call to an API using $http. The call to $http is originating from localhost:9000. The API is endpoint is available at localhost:9100/API/v1.0/context...

I am getting an error message saying "Refused to set header Cookie". From what I have read, the browser sets these headers for security reasons and these cannot be configured. According to the similar question here[similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255284/refused-to-set-unsafe-header-cookie-error-in-browser-yet-request-is-successful), I have tried enabling  crossDomain:true and withCredentials:true but to no effect.

Any answer on why this is happening would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the code

```
$http({
                        method: method,
                        url: urlpoint,
                        headers:headers,
                        params: query,
                        crossDomain: true

                    })
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        if (!data || data.length == 0)
                            data = $rootScope.getLocaleValue("EMPTY_RESPONSE");
                        operation.result.data = data;

                        $scope._afterMakeTestCall(operation, status,
                            headers, config);
                    });
```

And in the headers field, I have set

```
    headers['Cookie'] = 'cookieValue="something";';
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @Phil I have added the code

Answer (score 1):

After a long time of searching, I came across references stating that browser will not allow to set the Cookie header due to security vulnerabilities. It can only be done through headless browsers.